# MVC routing expect the Id when it sould not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have troubles with my routing:
I have in my controller this method:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetCase(CustomIdentity currentUser, string objectType, Guid objectId)
```

And in my routes

```
r.Match("CTRL/{id}", "CTRL", "details");
r.Match("CTRL/GetCase", "CTRL", "GetCase");
```

The problem is when i want to initiate a GET to my method:
I can do that only with

```
http://a.com/CTRL/GetCase/EE5014C2-C4AA-44E2-80F9-A23D01317790?objectType=123&objectId=1E5014C2-C4AA-44E2-80F9-A23D01317790
```

But i need

```
http://a.com/CTRL/GetCase?objectType=123&objectId=1E5014C2-C4AA-44E2-80F9-A23D01317790
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order of the route setup. The first URI...

```
http://a.com/CTRL/GetCase/EE5014C2-C4AA-44E2-80F9-A23D01317790?objectType=123&objectId=1E5014C2-C4AA-44E2-80F9-A23D01317790
```

matches the `CTRL/{id}` route you set up where `GetCase` in the URI satisfies {id} template parameter. The convention uses the first matched route it finds when mapping routes.

You need to change the order you set up the route. From what you've shown, that would be

```
r.Match("CTRL/GetCase", "CTRL", "GetCase");
r.Match("CTRL/{id}", "CTRL", "details");
```